# Tailwindcss v2 not applying the correct style to element (mt-5 styles with 3rem instead of 1.25rem)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Certain `styles` in my project are not applying correctly. The easiest example to illustrate is `mt-5` which according to the docs should be `1.25rem`, but instead, my project shows as `3rem`.

I've tried going to my `tailwind.config.js` and adding `important: true` to it and it does work! But I'm wondering if there's another way to fix this.

Comment: Could you provide us some code ?

Comment: Figured it out, it's because I'm inheriting tailwind styles from my component library. Still have no clue why the utility class for mt-5 has 3rem instead of 1.25rem. Since it doesn't look like the component library is tweaking the utility classes

Comment: Does Bottstrap present in your project? Bootstrap `mt-5` class [generates](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) `margin-top: 3rem !important`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka this might be the reason, going to take a look at the code and update here. Thanks!

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka nailed the problem. Bootstrap was used in the main repository and the component library did not use bootstrap, thus overiding the tailwind defaults.